# Differnce in Ajax post

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, authentication, passport.js

I have one post like this

```
app.post('/auth', passport.initialize(), passport.authenticate('local', { session: false,scope: [] }), serialize, generateToken, respond);
```

this is working correctly.

Now I have made above post as a function and calling from different page

```
accesstokenController.auth = function(req, res) {
  console.log('Here auth called');
    passport.initialize(), passport.authenticate(
      'local', {
        session: false,
        scope: []
      }), serialize, generateToken, respond
  };
```

and calling this method from differnt rout page.

This is not working means passport.intialize() or passport.authenticate is not being called

Router calling method

```
var oauth = require("../oauth/accesstoken");
router.post('/auth', function(req, res) {
    oauth.auth(req, res);
});
```

What's wrong there

Thanks

Comment: `, serialize, generateToken, respond` looks odd, in your first code they are additional route handerls, in your new code you do nothing with them.

Comment: How to make them similar

Comment: to call `passport.initialize()` you could do: `passport.initialize()(req, res, function(){ console.log('next')})`, but that could get messy, another idea would be to make auth an array like `accesstokenController.auth = [passport.initialize(), passport.au...];`

Comment: but will it work then router.post('/auth', function(req, res) {
    oauth.auth(req, res);
});

Comment: I am calling this method from other route file

Comment: I have updated the calling method

Comment: if auth is an array you can pass it like this if i remember correctly: `router.post('/auth', oauth.auth);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171904/discussion-between-md-parvez-alam-and-roland-starke).

Comment: I am doing the same

Answer (score 0):

See the express reference for
[app.method](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.post.method) 
and 
[passing middleware arguments](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples).

You can export an array of handler functions like so:

```
// ./oauth.js

exports.init = [
   // express_session({secret: 'use express-session if you like'),
   // passport.session(),
   passport.initialize()
];

exports.login = [
   passport.authenticate('local', options),
   serialize,
   generateToken,
   (req, res) => res.send('you are logged in')
];
```

and use them in your app/router:

```
// ./app.js

const auth = require('./oauth');

app.use(auth.init);
app.post('/login', auth.login);
```

To follow the [passport docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/),
you should configure the module and call `passport.initalize` (a function returning an express middleware function, hence the brackets) separately with `app.use`